# Error in setup feature selection package: 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement'

Tags: python, installation, feature-selection

I am trying to install a python feature selection package : http://featureselection.asu.edu/

After download and unzip the scikit tool, I followed the instruction and tried install like this:

```
$ pip install setup.py
```

I got error saying:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
```

Then I tried:

```
pip install --user setup.py
```

But getting the same error.
I also tried:

```
brew install setup.py
```

And got:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "setup.py" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Anyone has experience on why this happen?
Was it because my python version is 3.5, while in the requirement python is 2.7?

Comment: `python setup.py install`

Comment: .. and that will run the setup/install for the package you downloaded.

Comment: @jordanm and Grimmy Thanks a lot, that helped!